# Camunda: How to deploy a process using ReactJS fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch, camunda

I am trying to use Camunda's REST api to deploy a new process. However, I keep getting this HTTP response when my function is called.
Response:

```
{"type":"InvalidRequestException","message":"No deployment resources contained in the form upload."}
```

My jsx function

```
    async deployNewProcess(xmlData) {
    
    const formData = new FormData()
    const blob = new Blob([xmlData], {type:'application/octet-stream'})

    formData.append('upload', blob)

    const response = await fetch(`${baseurl}/deployment/create`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>',
            'Content-Length': '<calculated when request is sent>',
            'Host': '<calculated when request is sent>'
          },
        body: formData
    })
        .then(result => console.log("SUCCESS: ", result))
        .catch(err => console.log("ERROR: ", err))
}
```

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this post https://camunda.com/blog/2018/02/custom-tasklist-examples/
see the example code

here:
https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/b2c6c3892d3d8130c0951a1d3584be7969fec82a/snippets/camunda-tasklist-examples/camunda-react-app/src/middleware/api.js#L11

and here:
https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/b2c6c3892d3d8130c0951a1d3584be7969fec82a/snippets/camunda-tasklist-examples/camunda-react-app/src/actions/camunda-rest/deployment.js#L4